# Width calculation for blocks in grid

Tags: css

I'm trying to set up a grid of blocks, but even if it seems like I'm making the blocks to fill up 100 % of the container width. They don't seem to line up properly.

The first row should have one big block and three smaller ones. Second should be filled up by the remaining of the first big block, one small and one big block.

It seems as if the total width of the blocks are larger than the container width forcing it to go on the second row and messing up the layout.

Am I missing some property on one of my elements?

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  padding-bottom: calc(20% - 10px);
  vertical-align: top;
}

.block:nth-child(14),
.block:nth-child(18),
.block:nth-child(19),
.block:nth-child(20),
.block:nth-child(5),
.block:nth-child(6),
.block:nth-child(7),
.block:nth-child(8),
.block:nth-child(9) {
  margin-top: calc(-20% + 5px)
}

.block:nth-child(1),
.block:nth-child(11),
.block:nth-child(20),
.block:nth-child(6) {
  width: calc(40% - 10px);
  padding-bottom: calc(40% - 10px)
}

.block:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: calc(40% + 5px)
}

.block:nth-child(10) {
  margin-left: calc(-60% + 5px)
}

.block:nth-child(15) {
  margin-left: calc(-20% + 5px)
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d0c7dd"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #0c8eec"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d0c7dd"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #0c8eec"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div>
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks complicated and a nightmare to maintain. Could you provide an image of the desired result? Also consider CSS Grid or maybe Flexbox for layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the whitespace between the `div`s that make your blocks. So you boxes are 100%, PLUS the " " between the boxes.

Quick and easy solution is to remove the new lines / spaces between the `div`s.

Alternatively, add comments around the white space (see below).

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(20% - 10px);
  padding-bottom: calc(20% - 10px);
  vertical-align: top;
}

.block:nth-child(14),
.block:nth-child(18),
.block:nth-child(19),
.block:nth-child(20),
.block:nth-child(5),
.block:nth-child(6),
.block:nth-child(7),
.block:nth-child(8),
.block:nth-child(9) {
  margin-top: calc(-20% + 5px)
}

.block:nth-child(1),
.block:nth-child(11),
.block:nth-child(20),
.block:nth-child(6) {
  width: calc(40% - 10px);
  padding-bottom: calc(40% - 10px)
}

.block:nth-child(5) {
  margin-left: calc(40% + 5px)
}

.block:nth-child(10) {
  margin-left: calc(-60% + 5px)
}

.block:nth-child(15) {
  margin-left: calc(-20% + 5px)
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #d0c7dd"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #0c8eec"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #2be6d9"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #d0c7dd"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #0c8eec"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #f06859"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #68d2e7"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #001fc9"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #d040e9"></div><!--
 --><div class="block" style="background-color: #fd1341"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of the whitespaces. Ended up adding font-size: 0; to the .grid element.